# Xcode SKSpriteKit enumerateChildNodesWithName vs managed array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to break down my game so it can pass off functionality to other classes - eg. CollisionHandler etc. for example:

```
    [collisionHandler handleCollisions:enemies forPlayer:player];
```

There are two ways I can create the 'enemies' array.

I can maintain it myself, pushing and popping enemies as they are created and killed. But this means that in an enemy class, instead of just doing this..

```
    [self removeFromParent]
```

I would need to add more code to tell the main game scene to remove the item etc.

Or I can just create the array when I need it, using `enumerateChildNodesWithName`. For example, in my main game loop

```
    -(void)run
    {
      NSMutableArray *enemies = [self getNodesWithName:@"enemy"];
      [collisionHandler handleCollisions:enemies withPlayer:player];
    }

    -(NSMutableArray*)getNodesWithName:(NSString*)name
    {
      NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [self enumerateNodesWithName:@"enemy" usingBlock:^{[result addObject:node];}];
      return result;
    }
```

It all works fine using 2, and reduces the need to maintain my own arrays of enemies, game objects, bullets, etc

But my question is - is this going to become laggy when there are lots of items. Is enumerating and creating the array each frame hugely inefficient compared to maintain an array of objects myself? Or will iOS enumerate quickly enough not to be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS 8 SKNode’s -enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock: is slow. Reason being many developers were modifying the node tree while it was being enumerated which led to many crashes (NSMutableArray's modified while enumerated crash).

Given that, SKNode -enumerate.. was updated to be crash safe in those situations albeit now it is slower.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have thought enumerateNodesWithName is massively efficient, since it needs to do so many string comparisons.

What you could do, is create an NSMutableDictionary that contains all of your nodes as values, with their names as keys. Whenever you add a node to the scene, you just add it to your dictionary. That way, finding the node you want to remove is much quicker. Just make sure you keep the dictionary up to date.